# Multi authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin, logout

Hello I am trying to login an admin to my system and after doing everything i know,while logging in i am still getting error "The credentials dont match our records" Here is my code.
auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

logincontroller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)){
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

}
```

admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password',

    ];
    protected $table = 'admin';
}
```

login.blade

```
@if(count($errors)>0)
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                                @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.login')}}" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <fieldset>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">LOGIN</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>'''

web.php
```

```
Route::get('admin','Admin\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('admin','Admin\Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Comment: try change your form action to `action="{{ action('Admin\Auth\LoginController@login") }}"`

Comment: I did it but it is not working like that as well

Comment: make sure your username / email & password is correct. ensure the password hash is correct too.

Comment: It worked. The problem was regarding Hash. Thankyou